# Functions like array_merge with recursive processing

Tags: php

I have two such arrays.

```
$array_1 = array(
    'array_key' => array(
        'array_key_1' => 1,
        'array_key_2' => 2,
        'array_key_3' => 3,
    ),
);

$array_2 = array(
    'array_key' => array(
        'array_key_1' => null,
        'array_key_2' => null,
        'array_key_3' => null,
        'array_key_4' => null,
        'array_key_5' => null,
    ),
);
```

I would like to create a function to create a new array from these arrays, supplemented by an array whose keys do not exist.

```
$array_true = array(
    'array_key' => array(
        'array_key_1' => 1,
        'array_key_2' => 2,
        'array_key_3' => 3,
        'array_key_4' => null,
        'array_key_5' => null
    ),
);
```

I have created my own function for array_merge, but it does not support recursion, so if there is a better way to write it, I would appreciate your advice.

```
$array_1 = array(
    'array_key' => array(
        'array_key_1' => 1,
        'array_key_2' => 2,
        'array_key_3' => 3,
    ),
);

$array_2 = array(
    'array_key' => array(
        'array_key_1' => null,
        'array_key_2' => null,
        'array_key_3' => null,
        'array_key_4' => null,
        'array_key_5' => null,
    ),
);

// Ultimately, I would like to create such a function.
$array_true = array(
    'array_key' => array(
        'array_key_1' => 1,
        'array_key_2' => 2,
        'array_key_3' => 3,
        'array_key_4' => null,
        'array_key_5' => null
    ),
);

function my_merge_func($array_1,$array_2) {
    $merged =  array();
    foreach ($array_2 as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($array_1[ $key ])) {
            $merged[ $key ] = $value;
        } else {
            if (is_array($value)) {
              //  my_merge_func($array_1,$value);
                // I want to make it a recursive process since similar processing continues from here.
                foreach ($value as $key_1 => $value_1) {
                    if (empty($array_1[ $key ][ $key_1 ])) {
                        $merged[ $key ][ $key_1 ] = $value_1;
                    } else {
                        if (is_array($value_1)) {
                            foreach ($value_1 as $key_2 => $value_2) {
                                $merged[ $key ][ $key_1 ][ $key_2 ] = $value_2;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $merged[ $key ][ $key_1 ] = $array_1[ $key ][ $key_1 ];
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $merged[ $key ] = $array_1[ $key ];
            }
        }
    }
    return $merged;
};
var_dump(my_merge_func($array_1,$array_2));

var_dump($array_true);

var_dump(my_merge_func($array_1,$array_2) ===  $array_true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @student91, I was able to create the ideal function.
Thank you very much.

Completed code

```
function my_merge_func($array_1, $array_2) {
    $merged = $array_1;
    foreach ($array_2 as $key => $value) {
        if (
            empty($array_1[ $key ])
        ) {
            $merged[ $key ] = $value;
        } else if(is_array($value) && is_array($array_1[ $key ])) {
            $merged[ $key ] = my_merge_func($array_1[ $key ], $value);
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function my_merge_func($array_1, $array_2) {
    $merged = $array_1; //EDITED: previously said $merged = array();
    foreach ($array_2 as $key => $value) {
        if (
            empty($array_1[ $key ])
            || !is_array($array_1[ $key ])
            || !is_array($value)
        ) {
            $merged[ $key ] = $value;
        } else {
            $merged[ $key ] = my_merge_func($array_1[ $key ], $value);
        }
    }
    return $merged; // EDITED: previously, return statement was missing.
}
```

Some things to consider:

- This might give infinite loops if the array is recursive: `$a = []; $b = [&$a]; $a []= &$b; my_merge_func($a,$b);` gives an infinite loop (I think).
- I made it such that for `$a = ['foo' => ['bar' => 'a']];` and `$b = ['foo' => 'baz']` you have `my_merge_func($a,$b) = ['foo' => 'baz']` even though `$a['foo']` is an array.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It just doesn't seem to work with the code you gave me.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [array_merge_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php), esp. the comment by [gabriel](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#92195)

Comment: @gabriel
Thanks.
However, array_merge_recursive does recursive processing but it joins all arrays.
I want to merge only when there was no key.