# I want to merge two arrays while keeping the array keys

Tags: php

I want to merge two arrays while keeping the array keys

I want to create $array_true merging $array_1 and $array_2 as follows.

```
$array_1 = array(
    'some_one' => 'some_text',
    'array_1'  => array(
        'value_1_1',
        'value_1_2'
    ),

);

$array_2 = array(
    'some_one' => 'some_text_2',
    'array_0'  => array(
        'value_0_1',
        'value_0_2'
    ),
    'array_1'  => array(
        'value_defaults_1_1',
        'value_defaults_1_2'
    ),
    'array_2'  => array(
        'value_defaults_2_1',
        'value_defaults_2_2'
    ),
);

// Ultimately, I would like to create such a function.
$array_true = array(
    'some_one' => 'some_text',
    'array_0'  => array(
        'value_0_1',
        'value_0_2'
    ),
    'array_1'  => array(
        'value_1_1',
        'value_1_2'
    ),
    'array_2'  => array(
        'value_defaults_2_1',
        'value_defaults_2_2'
    ),
);

function my_merge_func($array_1, $array_2) {
    $merged = $array_1;
    foreach ($array_2 as $key => $value) {
        if (
            empty($array_1[ $key ])
        ) {
            $merged[ $key ] = $value;
        } else if(is_array($value) && is_array($array_1[ $key ])) {
            $merged[ $key ] = my_merge_func($array_1[ $key ], $value);
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}
var_dump(my_merge_func($array_1,$array_2));

var_dump($array_true);

var_dump(my_merge_func($array_1,$array_2) ===  $array_true);
```

my_merge_func will be the one I created in the previous question

[Functions like array_merge with recursive processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73384745/functions-like-array-merge-with-recursive-processing/73396476#73396476)

As it is now, the array looks like this.

```
array(4) {
  ["some_one"]=>
  string(9) "some_text"
  ["array_1"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "value_1_1"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "value_1_2"
  }
  ["array_0"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "value_0_1"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "value_0_2"
  }
  ["array_2"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "value_defaults_2_1"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "value_defaults_2_2"
  }
}
```

I would appreciate your advice.

This function was originally created to merge these two functions as follows.

```
$array_1 = array(
    'array_key' => array(
        'array_key_1' => 1,
        'array_key_2' => 2,
        'array_key_3' => 3,
    ),
);

$array_2 = array(
    'array_key' => array(
        'array_key_1' => null,
        'array_key_2' => null,
        'array_key_3' => null,
        'array_key_4' => null,
        'array_key_5' => null,
    ),
);

// Ultimately, I would like to create such a function.
$array_true = array(
    'array_key' => array(
        'array_key_1' => 1,
        'array_key_2' => 2,
        'array_key_3' => 3,
        'array_key_4' => null,
        'array_key_5' => null
    ),
);
```

Comment: your expected result and the output you share are identical. what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @PragneshChauhan Thanks for the comment.
In ==, the last line would be true.

My goal is to get them in the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't with the function you've created; that works exactly like it should. The problem is your very last line of code:

```php
var_dump(my_merge_func($array_1,$array_2) ===  $array_true);
```

Of course, you'd just like to check whether the resulting array matches your desired result. If you have a look at the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) for the array comparison operators, you'll read the following for the triple equals (`===`) operator:

> **true** if `$a` and `$b` have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.

While all of your value pairs have the exact same key/value-pairs and types, the order is not the same, which is why the `===` returns false. Functionally, the arrays are exaclty the same and the order does not matter at all. The quick fix is to change to a double equals:

```php
var_dump(my_merge_func($array_1,$array_2) == $array_true);
```

It doesn't account for type safety, but it does the trick for this application. You can adjust the function to get the order the same as well:

```php
function my_merge_func($a, $b) {
    $merged = $b;
    foreach($a as $key => $value) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $b)) {
            $merged[$key] = $value;
        } else if(is_array($value) && is_array($b[$key])) {
            $merged[$key] = my_merge_func($value, $b[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}
```

Please note that the order will only be guaranteed in this specific case, but that order doesn't matter -at all- for associative arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In ==, the last line would be true. My goal is to get them in the same order.

Comment: I updated my response with a way to get the order the same.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

With the code you provided, I am no longer able to merge arrays that do not have the same key!

Is it possible to loop based on $a instead of looping based on $b?

Or can you think of another way?

Comment: Please update your question with any additional code that should work. But basically I can already tell you that it is not possible to achieve what you want because there'll always be a mix of requirements. In your example, `$array_1`'s values will take precedence over `$array_2`, but you want the order of `$array_2` to take precedence over `$array_1`. Without telling the function which array should have precedence over the other for both order and values, there is no way for the function to know and to produce the right result in all cases.

Comment: The code is appended to the question.
Please see this question for more information.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73384745/functions-like-array-merge-with-recursive-processing/73396476#73396476

You are correct.
The value is `$array_1`
The order is `$array_2`.
I want to give priority to `$array_2`.